# Speeding up associations in model specs with FactoryGirl - create vs build vs build_stubbed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot

Say I have models `User` and `Post`, a user `has_many` posts and a post `belongs_to` a user.

When I write a spec for `Post`, my first instinct is to write something like this:

```
before do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
  @post = @user.posts.new(title: "Foo", content: "bar)
end

... tests for @post go here ...
```

But this is going to create a new User - hitting the database - for every single test, which is going to slow things down. Is there a better way to do this that will speed my tests up and avoid hitting the DB so often?

As I understand it, I can't use `FactoryGirl.build :user` because, even though it won't hit the DB, the associations won't work properly because `@user` won't have an ID and so `@post.user` won't work (it returns `nil`.)

I could use `FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :user` which created a "fake persisted" `@user` which does have an ID, but `@post.user` still returns nil. Does `build_stubbed` have any practical advantage over `build` when I'm testing things related to associations?

I suppose I could use `build_stubbed` stub `@post.user` so it returns `@user`... is there any reason this might be a bad idea?

Or should I just use `create` and accept the speed hit?

The only other alternative I can think of would be to set up @user in a `before(:all)` block which seems like a bad idea.

What's the best way to write these kind of tests in a clean, concise way that avoids making too many DB queries?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't want your tests to be hitting the database, this is what you would have to do.

```
before do
  @user = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :user
  @post = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :post
  @user.stub(:posts).and_return([@post])
  @post.stub(:user).and_return(@user)
end
```

Note: Be careful when using `before(:all)`. It doesn't get executed in a transaction. So whatever you create in `before(:all)` will get left behind in the database and might cause conflict with other tests

About `FactoryGirl.build`, it builds the object, but creates the associations.

For eg:

```
factory :user do
  association posts
end

FactoryGirl.build(:user) #this creates posts in the database even though you are only building the parent object(user)
```

Answer (score 17):

**Short Answer**

```
@user = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:user)
@post = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:post, :user => @user)
```

This will make @post.user work without ever hitting the database.

**Long Answer**

My recommendation would be to wait on the `before` block until you're sure you need it. Instead, build the data you need for each individual test and extract duplication to methods or new factories as you find it.

Also, do you actually need to reference the user in every single test? Having `@user` available in every test says to other developers that it's important everywhere.

Lastly, assuming that the user association is also declared in your post factory, you'll automatically get a working `post.user` when you do `build_stubbed(:post)`.

Answer (score 11):

It can be easy to forget the differences between `create`, `build`, and `build_stubbed`. Here's a quick reference for those in the same situation (as this page ranks highly in search results).

```
# Returns a User instance that's not saved (does not write to DB)
user = build(:user)

# Returns a saved User instance (writes to DB)
user = create(:user)

# Returns a hash of attributes that can be used to build a User instance
attrs = attributes_for(:user)

# Returns an object with all defined attributes stubbed out
stub = build_stubbed(:user)

# Passing a block to any of the methods above will yield the return object
create(:user) do |user|
  user.posts.create(attributes_for(:post))
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/deaf5529fb93945dea50e45af6c7d8817863da12/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories)

Answer (score 1):

From the document of factory girl, you can identify strategy `build` for `user` in association in `post` factory like this:

```
factory :post do
  association :user, factory: :user, strategy: :build
end
```

So that you can `build` a `post` without save `user`

```
post = build(:post)
post.new_record?        # => true
post.author.new_record? # => true
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick explanation of differences:
FactoryGirl.create will create new object and associations (if the factory has any) for it. They will all be persisted in db. Also, it will trigger both model and database validations. 
Callbacks after(:build) and after(:create) will be called after the factory is saved. Also before(:create) will be called before the factory is saved.

FactoryGirl.build won't save an object, but will still make requests to a database if the factory has associations. It will trigger validations only for associated objects.
Callback after(:build) will be called after the factory is built.

FactoryGirl.build_stubbed does not call database at all. It creates and assigns attributes to an object to make it behave like an instantiated object. It provides a fake id and created_at. Associations, if any, will be created via build_stubbed too. It will not trigger any validations.

Read full explanation [here](https://kolosek.com/factory-girl-build-vs-build_stub)